# How to get multiple values in same cell in Oracle

Tags: oracle, string-aggregation

I have a table in Oracle where there are two columns. In the first column, sometimes there are duplicate values that corresspond to a different value in the second column. How can I write a query that shows only unique values of the first column and all possible values from the second column?

The table looks somewhat like below

```
COLUMN_1   |   COLUMN_2

NUMBER_1   |       4
NUMBER_2   |       4 
NUMBER_3   |       1
NUMBER_3   |       6
NUMBER_4   |       3
NUMBER_4   |       4
NUMBER_4   |       5
NUMBER_4   |       6
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `listagg()` if you are using `Oracle 11G` or higher like

```
SELECT 
    COLUMN_1,
    LISTAGG(COLUMN_2, '|') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY COLUMN_2) "ListValues"
FROM table1
GROUP BY COLUMN_1
```

Else, see this link for an alternative for lower versions

[Oracle equivalent of MySQL group_concat](http://www.patlaf.com/oracle-equivalent-of-mysql-group_concat/)